# Excel Solver in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement something like this

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-solver-to-rate-sports-teams-HA001124601.aspx

in python with python libraries only (not calling Excel solver).

Can someone point me to the right libraries to be using + some dive-in tutorials to get started ?

Comment: If I may ask, why do you want to do this?  Excel formulas can be mimicked with Python native functions -- writing a parser is a much more involved process.

Comment: I found the question useful, found a tool at https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

Answer (score 30):

You are looking for NumPy (matrix manipulation and number-crunching) and SciPy (optimization).
To get started, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375094/numpy-learning-resources

I worked out the given example as follows:

- I opened the sample Excel files in OpenOffice
- I copied the team-data (without headers) to a new sheet and saved as teams.csv
- I copied the game-data (without headers) to a new sheet and saved as games.csv

then in Python:

```
import csv
import numpy
import scipy.optimize

def readCsvFile(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as inf:
        return list(csv.reader(inf))

# Get team data
team = readCsvFile('teams.csv')  # list of num,name
numTeams = len(team)

# Get game data
game = readCsvFile('games.csv')  # list of game,home,away,homescore,awayscore
numGames = len(game)

# Now, we have the NFL teams for 2002 and data on all games played.
# From this, we wish to forecast the score of future games.
# We are going to assume that each team has an inherent performance-factor,
# and that there is a bonus for home-field advantage; then the
# relative final score between a home team and an away team can be
# calculated as (home advantage) + (home team factor) - (away team factor)

# First we create a matrix M which will hold the data on
# who played whom in each game and who had home-field advantage.
m_rows = numTeams + 1
m_cols = numGames
M = numpy.zeros( (m_rows, m_cols) )

# Then we create a vector S which will hold the final
# relative scores for each game.
s_cols = numGames
S = numpy.zeros(s_cols)

# Loading M and S with game data
for col,gamedata in enumerate(game):
    gameNum,home,away,homescore,awayscore = gamedata
    # In the csv data, teams are numbered starting at 1
    # So we let home-team advantage be 'team 0' in our matrix
    M[0, col]         =  1.0   # home team advantage
    M[int(home), col] =  1.0
    M[int(away), col] = -1.0
    S[col]            = int(homescore) - int(awayscore)


# Now, if our theoretical model is correct, we should be able
# to find a performance-factor vector W such that W*M == S
#
# In the real world, we will never find a perfect match,
# so what we are looking for instead is W which results in S'
# such that the least-mean-squares difference between S and S'
# is minimized.

# Initial guess at team weightings:
# 2.0 points home-team advantage, and all teams equally strong
init_W = numpy.array([2.0]+[0.0]*numTeams)  

def errorfn(w,m,s):
    return w.dot(m) - s

W = scipy.optimize.leastsq(errorfn, init_W, args=(M,S))

homeAdvantage = W[0][0]   # 2.2460937500005356
teamStrength = W[0][1:]   # numpy.array([-151.31111318, -136.36319652, ... ])

# Team strengths have meaning only by linear comparison;
# we can add or subtract any constant to all of them without
# changing the meaning.
# To make them easier to understand, we want to shift them
# such that the average is 0.0
teamStrength -= teamStrength.mean()

for t,s in zip(team,teamStrength):
    print "{0:>10}: {1: .7}".format(t[1],s)
```

results in

```
       Ari: -9.8897569
       Atl:  5.0581597
      Balt: -2.1178819
      Buff: -0.27413194
  Carolina: -3.2720486
      Chic: -5.2654514
      Cinn: -10.503646
      Clev:  1.2338542
      Dall: -8.4779514
       Den:  4.8901042
       Det: -9.1727431
        GB:  3.5800347
      Hous: -9.4390625
      Indy:  1.1689236
      Jack: -0.2015625
        KC:  6.1112847
     Miami:  6.0588542
      Minn: -3.0092014
        NE:  4.0262153
        NO:  2.4251736
       NYG:  0.82725694
       NYJ:  3.1689236
       Oak:  10.635243
      Phil:  8.2987847
      Pitt:  2.6994792
 St. Louis: -3.3352431
 San Diego: -0.72065972
        SF:  0.63524306
   Seattle: -1.2512153
     Tampa:  8.8019097
      Tenn:  1.7640625
      Wash: -4.4529514
```

which is the same result shown in the spreadsheet.

Comment: You should accept his answer, then.  Click on the check mark on the left.

Comment: I now this is very old but do you still have the CSV file examples as I get the error     M[int(home), col] =  1.0
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Home Team' when trying to run it

Comment: I don't - but it sounds like you didn't remove the header row.

Answer (score 4):

This page lists a number of solver libraries for Python which you might use:

- [Python solvers](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200802/python_solvers.html)

Answer (score 3):

**PuLP** is a linear programming modeller in python. It can do everything that the excel solver can do.

> PuLP is a free open source software written in Python. It is used to
>   describe optimisation problems as mathematical models. PuLP can then
>   call any of numerous external LP solvers (CBC, GLPK, CPLEX, Gurobi
>   etc) to solve this model and then use python commands to manipulate
>   and display the solution.

There is a [detailed introduction about PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) and a manual on how to model optimization problems with PuLP in python.

Modelling example

```
# Import PuLP modeler functions
from pulp import *

# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("Example_Problem", LpMinimize)

# Declare decision variables
var_x = LpVariable(name="x", lowBound=0, cat="Continuous")
var_y = LpVariable(name="y", cat="Integer")

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += var_x + 2 * var_y

# The constraints are added to 'prob'
prob += var_x == (-1) * var_y
prob += var_x <= 15
prob += var_x > 0

# The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
prob.solve()

# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

# Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Pyspread](http://pyspread.sourceforge.net/), a spreadsheet application completely written in Python.  Individual cells can hold Python expressions and can access all of the Python modules.