# Python function, solve for input given the output

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

I would like to what's the best way in Python to find a input value given an output, on a customized function. for instance, I have function_a (a, b, c, d), which returns e as an answer; what I'm trying to achieve is to reverse engineer the function without rewriting a new function; so given a target value of e, and a, b, c I would like to find the value of d.

One way I can think of is to give the d a range, and iterate through the function and compare the e each time until it finds an answer, if the d is outside of the range, then no answer would be found.

Is there any other way which could be used?
Many thanks

Jim

Comment: Hi Kong, I think your question is too broad, if you don't specify the constraints here. What if 'd' is a dictionary, then the problem statement becomes more complex. And what if inside the function_a(), you are changing the state of outer variable, that will be missed in reverse engineering. So can you specify the constraints here, so that a possible solution can be put up.

Comment: If your parameters are only numbers, you would be required to algebraically re-arrange the equation for `d` in terms of `a`, `b`, `c` and `e` and write a new function for that. Otherwise, @shubhendu-endu is right about it being too broad.

Comment: Hi @shubhendu-endu, thanks for your reply. so for my particular example, all a,b,c,d and the output e are arrays, the state of the variables are static so they will not be changed. ideally, what I'm trying to do is to have a Excel Solver like functionalities; by setting a target value of e, so it can find what should the value be of other parameters (a-d); and similar to the Excel Solver, only one variable is allowed to be changed at a time.

Comment: This one can show you some way ->   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634317/excel-solver-in-python/46340060  (Answer by Hugh) Just look at the approach and see if it helps in any way. Here they have tried to mimic the same functionality which was verified with the same output.